# Undefined Index Error Reporting in WAMP and PHP

Tags: php, wamp, error-reporting

I'm using wamp to develop a php application.  My problem is that everytime I call a variable that sometimes happens to not have a value, I get an error that says it's an undefined index.  Is there a way to change the error reporting to not display this error?  I have to use isset to determine if it's set or not before I output the variable, but I don't want to have to do this.  There are areas of my application that make this method inefficient.

Comment: You do realize that every warning PHP generates (even if it isn't shown) incurs a performance penalty? Talk about inefficient...

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to change error_reporting level you should check, is variable exists, before using it. You may use

```
 if(isset($var))
```

for it. You may add some function, to not write it always. Example:

```
 function getPost($name,$default=null){
     return isset($_POST[$name])?$_POST[$name]:$default;
 }
```

**Usage:**

```
getPost('id');
getPost('name','Not Logged In');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just turn off the mechanism in php.ini.

This thread would help you.

http://www.wampserver.com/phorum/read.php?2,70609,70700

But it generally its better to take care of undefined variables as they might save you some run time trouble.

Update:

In php.ini change

error_reporting = E_ALL to error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE

Comment: I may have explained the situation badly.  What I want to do is instead of an undefined variable returning an error when it's called, I want to have it be returned as a blank string($x = '') or something like that.  Not change the style of the error reports.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to get around this:
`error_reporting(0)` Use this at the top of your script
set `display_errors = Off` in php.ini
Use '@' before the statement that generates an error

But unless you are writing something trivial you absolutely *must* use `array_key_exists` or `if(!empty($arrayName['key']))` for everything sent by the user.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

if(!isset($var)) $var="";

Answer (score 0):

PHP.ini files reside in both :

**bin\php\php5.x**

and

**bin\apache\apache2.x\bin**

be sure to ***make the changes in the apache folder version***.

---

Also setting :

*display_errors = Off*

*display_startup_errors = Off*

*error_reporting = E_ALL*

*log_errors = On*

leaves errors from being displayed on the client, but still allows them to be logged in the error log.